# sortable.js don't work with other script condition.js and <body onload="contition()">

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-sortable

hi i run 2 scripts the first is

sorttable.js

```js
/*
  SortTable
  version 2
  7th April 2007
  Stuart Langridge, http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/
  
  Instructions:
  Download this file
  Add <script src="sorttable.js"></script> to your HTML
  Add class="sortable" to any table you'd like to make sortable
  Click on the headers to sort
  
  Thanks to many, many people for contributions and suggestions.
  Licenced as X11: http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/licence.html
  This basically means: do what you want with it.
*/

 
var stIsIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false;

sorttable = {
  init: function() {
    // quit if this function has already been called
    if (arguments.callee.done) return;
    // flag this function so we don't do the same thing twice
    arguments.callee.done = true;
    // kill the timer
    if (_timer) clearInterval(_timer);
    
    if (!document.createElement || !document.getElementsByTagName) return;
    
    sorttable.DATE_RE = /^(\d\d?)[\/\.-](\d\d?)[\/\.-]((\d\d)?\d\d)$/;
    
    forEach(document.getElementsByTagName('table'), function(table) {
      if (table.className.search(/\bsortable\b/) != -1) {
        sorttable.makeSortable(table);
      }
    });
    
  },
  
  makeSortable: function(table) {
    if (table.getElementsByTagName('thead').length == 0) {
      // table doesn't have a tHead. Since it should have, create one and
      // put the first table row in it.
      the = document.createElement('thead');
      the.appendChild(table.rows[0]);
      table.insertBefore(the,table.firstChild);
    }
    // Safari doesn't support table.tHead, sigh
    if (table.tHead == null) table.tHead = table.getElementsByTagName('thead')[0];
    
    if (table.tHead.rows.length != 1) return; // can't cope with two header rows
    
    // Sorttable v1 put rows with a class of "sortbottom" at the bottom (as
    // "total" rows, for example). This is B&R, since what you're supposed
    // to do is put them in a tfoot. So, if there are sortbottom rows,
    // for backwards compatibility, move them to tfoot (creating it if needed).
    sortbottomrows = [];
    for (var i=0; i<table.rows.length; i++) {
      if (table.rows[i].className.search(/\bsortbottom\b/) != -1) {
        sortbottomrows[sortbottomrows.length] = table.rows[i];
      }
    }
    if (sortbottomrows) {
      if (table.tFoot == null) {
        // table doesn't have a tfoot. Create one.
        tfo = document.createElement('tfoot');
        table.appendChild(tfo);
      }
      for (var i=0; i<sortbottomrows.length; i++) {
        tfo.appendChild(sortbottomrows[i]);
      }
      delete sortbottomrows;
    }
    
    // work through each column and calculate its type
    headrow = table.tHead.rows[0].cells;
    for (var i=0; i<headrow.length; i++) {
      // manually override the type with a sorttable_type attribute
      if (!headrow[i].className.match(/\bsorttable_nosort\b/)) { // skip this col
        mtch = headrow[i].className.match(/\bsorttable_([a-z0-9]+)\b/);
        if (mtch) { override = mtch[1]; }
       if (mtch && typeof sorttable["sort_"+override] == 'function') {
         headrow[i].sorttable_sortfunction = sorttable["sort_"+override];
       } else {
         headrow[i].sorttable_sortfunction = sorttable.guessType(table,i);
       }
       // make it clickable to sort
       headrow[i].sorttable_columnindex = i;
       headrow[i].sorttable_tbody = table.tBodies[0];
       dean_addEvent(headrow[i],"click", function(e) {

          if (this.className.search(/\bsorttable_sorted\b/) != -1) {
            // if we're already sorted by this column, just 
            // reverse the table, which is quicker
            sorttable.reverse(this.sorttable_tbody);
            this.className = this.className.replace('sorttable_sorted',
                                                    'sorttable_sorted_reverse');
            this.removeChild(document.getElementById('sorttable_sortfwdind'));
            sortrevind = document.createElement('span');
            sortrevind.id = "sorttable_sortrevind";
            sortrevind.innerHTML = stIsIE ? '&nbsp<font face="webdings">5</font>' : '&nbsp;&#x25B4;';
            this.appendChild(sortrevind);
            return;
          }
          if (this.className.search(/\bsorttable_sorted_reverse\b/) != -1) {
            // if we're already sorted by this column in reverse, just 
            // re-reverse the table, which is quicker
            sorttable.reverse(this.sorttable_tbody);
            this.className = this.className.replace('sorttable_sorted_reverse',
                                                    'sorttable_sorted');
            this.removeChild(document.getElementById('sorttable_sortrevind'));
            sortfwdind = document.createElement('span');
            sortfwdind.id = "sorttable_sortfwdind";
            sortfwdind.innerHTML = stIsIE ? '&nbsp<font face="webdings">6</font>' : '&nbsp;&#x25BE;';
            this.appendChild(sortfwdind);
            return;
          }
          
          // remove sorttable_sorted classes
          theadrow = this.parentNode;
          forEach(theadrow.childNodes, function(cell) {
            if (cell.nodeType == 1) { // an element
              cell.className = cell.className.replace('sorttable_sorted_reverse','');
              cell.className = cell.className.replace('sorttable_sorted','');
            }
          });
          sortfwdind = document.getElementById('sorttable_sortfwdind');
          if (sortfwdind) { sortfwdind.parentNode.removeChild(sortfwdind); }
          sortrevind = document.getElementById('sorttable_sortrevind');
          if (sortrevind) { sortrevind.parentNode.removeChild(sortrevind); }
          
          this.className += ' sorttable_sorted';
          sortfwdind = document.createElement('span');
          sortfwdind.id = "sorttable_sortfwdind";
          sortfwdind.innerHTML = stIsIE ? '&nbsp<font face="webdings">6</font>' : '&nbsp;&#x25BE;';
          this.appendChild(sortfwdind);

         // build an array to sort. This is a Schwartzian transform thing,
         // i.e., we "decorate" each row with the actual sort key,
         // sort based on the sort keys, and then put the rows back in order
         // which is a lot faster because you only do getInnerText once per row
         row_array = [];
         col = this.sorttable_columnindex;
         rows = this.sorttable_tbody.rows;
         for (var j=0; j<rows.length; j++) {
           row_array[row_array.length] = [sorttable.getInnerText(rows[j].cells[col]), rows[j]];
         }
         /* If you want a stable sort, uncomment the following line */
sorttable.shaker_sort(row_array, this.sorttable_sortfunction);
//row_array.sort(this.sorttable_sortfunction);
         
         tb = this.sorttable_tbody;
         for (var j=0; j<row_array.length; j++) {
           tb.appendChild(row_array[j][1]);
         }
         
         delete row_array;
       });
     }
    }
  },
  
  guessType: function(table, column) {
    // guess the type of a column based on its first non-blank row
    sortfn = sorttable.sort_alpha;
    for (var i=0; i<table.tBodies[0].rows.length; i++) {
      text = sorttable.getInnerText(table.tBodies[0].rows[i].cells[column]);
      if (text != '') {
        if (text.match(/^-?[£$€]?[\d,.]+%?$/)) {
          return sorttable.sort_numeric;
        }
        // check for a date: dd/mm/yyyy or dd/mm/yy 
        // can have / or . or - as separator
        // can be mm/dd as well
        possdate = text.match(sorttable.DATE_RE)
        if (possdate) {
          // looks like a date
          first = parseInt(possdate[1]);
          second = parseInt(possdate[2]);
          if (first > 12) {
            // definitely dd/mm
            return sorttable.sort_ddmm;
          } else if (second > 12) {
            return sorttable.sort_mmdd;
          } else {
            // looks like a date, but we can't tell which, so assume
            // that it's dd/mm (English imperialism!) and keep looking
            sortfn = sorttable.sort_ddmm;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return sortfn;
  },
  
  getInnerText: function(node) {
    // gets the text we want to use for sorting for a cell.
    // strips leading and trailing whitespace.
    // this is *not* a generic getInnerText function; it's special to sorttable.
    // for example, you can override the cell text with a customkey attribute.
    // it also gets .value for <input> fields.
    
    hasInputs = (typeof node.getElementsByTagName == 'function') &&
                 node.getElementsByTagName('input').length;
    
    if (node.getAttribute("sorttable_customkey") != null) {
      return node.getAttribute("sorttable_customkey");
    }
    else if (typeof node.textContent != 'undefined' && !hasInputs) {
      return node.textContent.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    }
    else if (typeof node.innerText != 'undefined' && !hasInputs) {
      return node.innerText.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    }
    else if (typeof node.text != 'undefined' && !hasInputs) {
      return node.text.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    }
    else {
      switch (node.nodeType) {
        case 3:
          if (node.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'input') {
            return node.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
          }
        case 4:
          return node.nodeValue.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
          break;
        case 1:
        case 11:
          var innerText = '';
          for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
            innerText += sorttable.getInnerText(node.childNodes[i]);
          }
          return innerText.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
          break;
        default:
          return '';
      }
    }
  },
  
  reverse: function(tbody) {
    // reverse the rows in a tbody
    newrows = [];
    for (var i=0; i<tbody.rows.length; i++) {
      newrows[newrows.length] = tbody.rows[i];
    }
    for (var i=newrows.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
       tbody.appendChild(newrows[i]);
    }
    delete newrows;
  },
  
  /* sort functions
     each sort function takes two parameters, a and b
     you are comparing a[0] and b[0] */
  sort_numeric: function(a,b) {
    aa = parseFloat(a[0].replace(/[^0-9.-]/g,''));
    if (isNaN(aa)) aa = 0;
    bb = parseFloat(b[0].replace(/[^0-9.-]/g,'')); 
    if (isNaN(bb)) bb = 0;
    return aa-bb;
  },
  sort_alpha: function(a,b) {
    if (a[0]==b[0]) return 0;
    if (a[0]<b[0]) return -1;
    return 1;
  },
  sort_ddmm: function(a,b) {
    mtch = a[0].match(sorttable.DATE_RE);
    y = mtch[3]; m = mtch[2]; d = mtch[1];
    if (m.length == 1) m = '0'+m;
    if (d.length == 1) d = '0'+d;
    dt1 = y+m+d;
    mtch = b[0].match(sorttable.DATE_RE);
    y = mtch[3]; m = mtch[2]; d = mtch[1];
    if (m.length == 1) m = '0'+m;
    if (d.length == 1) d = '0'+d;
    dt2 = y+m+d;
    if (dt1==dt2) return 0;
    if (dt1<dt2) return -1;
    return 1;
  },
  sort_mmdd: function(a,b) {
    mtch = a[0].match(sorttable.DATE_RE);
    y = mtch[3]; d = mtch[2]; m = mtch[1];
    if (m.length == 1) m = '0'+m;
    if (d.length == 1) d = '0'+d;
    dt1 = y+m+d;
    mtch = b[0].match(sorttable.DATE_RE);
    y = mtch[3]; d = mtch[2]; m = mtch[1];
    if (m.length == 1) m = '0'+m;
    if (d.length == 1) d = '0'+d;
    dt2 = y+m+d;
    if (dt1==dt2) return 0;
    if (dt1<dt2) return -1;
    return 1;
  },
  
  shaker_sort: function(list, comp_func) {
    // A stable sort function to allow multi-level sorting of data
    // see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail_sort
    // thanks to Joseph Nahmias
    var b = 0;
    var t = list.length - 1;
    var swap = true;

    while(swap) {
        swap = false;
        for(var i = b; i < t; ++i) {
            if ( comp_func(list[i], list[i+1]) > 0 ) {
                var q = list[i]; list[i] = list[i+1]; list[i+1] = q;
                swap = true;
            }
        } // for
        t--;

        if (!swap) break;

        for(var i = t; i > b; --i) {
            if ( comp_func(list[i], list[i-1]) < 0 ) {
                var q = list[i]; list[i] = list[i-1]; list[i-1] = q;
                swap = true;
            }
        } // for
        b++;

    } // while(swap)
  }  
}

/* ******************************************************************
   Supporting functions: bundled here to avoid depending on a library
   ****************************************************************** */

// Dean Edwards/Matthias Miller/John Resig

/* for Mozilla/Opera9 */
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", sorttable.init, false);
}

/* for Internet Explorer */
/*@cc_on @*/
/*@if (@_win32)
    document.write("<script id=__ie_onload defer src=javascript:void(0)><\/script>");
    var script = document.getElementById("__ie_onload");
    script.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == "complete") {
            sorttable.init(); // call the onload handler
        }
    };
/*@end @*/

/* for Safari */
if (/WebKit/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) { // sniff
    var _timer = setInterval(function() {
        if (/loaded|complete/.test(document.readyState)) {
            sorttable.init(); // call the onload handler
        }
    }, 10);
}

/* for other browsers */
window.onload = sorttable.init;

// written by Dean Edwards, 2005
// with input from Tino Zijdel, Matthias Miller, Diego Perini

// http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2005/10/add-event/

function dean_addEvent(element, type, handler) {
 if (element.addEventListener) {
  element.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
 } else {
  // assign each event handler a unique ID
  if (!handler.$$guid) handler.$$guid = dean_addEvent.guid++;
  // create a hash table of event types for the element
  if (!element.events) element.events = {};
  // create a hash table of event handlers for each element/event pair
  var handlers = element.events[type];
  if (!handlers) {
   handlers = element.events[type] = {};
   // store the existing event handler (if there is one)
   if (element["on" + type]) {
    handlers[0] = element["on" + type];
   }
  }
  // store the event handler in the hash table
  handlers[handler.$$guid] = handler;
  // assign a global event handler to do all the work
  element["on" + type] = handleEvent;
 }
};
// a counter used to create unique IDs
dean_addEvent.guid = 1;

function removeEvent(element, type, handler) {
 if (element.removeEventListener) {
  element.removeEventListener(type, handler, false);
 } else {
  // delete the event handler from the hash table
  if (element.events && element.events[type]) {
   delete element.events[type][handler.$$guid];
  }
 }
};

function handleEvent(event) {
 var returnValue = true;
 // grab the event object (IE uses a global event object)
 event = event || fixEvent(((this.ownerDocument || this.document || this).parentWindow || window).event);
 // get a reference to the hash table of event handlers
 var handlers = this.events[event.type];
 // execute each event handler
 for (var i in handlers) {
  this.$$handleEvent = handlers[i];
  if (this.$$handleEvent(event) === false) {
   returnValue = false;
  }
 }
 return returnValue;
};

function fixEvent(event) {
 // add W3C standard event methods
 event.preventDefault = fixEvent.preventDefault;
 event.stopPropagation = fixEvent.stopPropagation;
 return event;
};
fixEvent.preventDefault = function() {
 this.returnValue = false;
};
fixEvent.stopPropagation = function() {
  this.cancelBubble = true;
}

// Dean's forEach: http://dean.edwards.name/base/forEach.js
/*
 forEach, version 1.0
 Copyright 2006, Dean Edwards
 License: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
*/

// array-like enumeration
if (!Array.forEach) { // mozilla already supports this
 Array.forEach = function(array, block, context) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   block.call(context, array[i], i, array);
  }
 };
}

// generic enumeration
Function.prototype.forEach = function(object, block, context) {
 for (var key in object) {
  if (typeof this.prototype[key] == "undefined") {
   block.call(context, object[key], key, object);
  }
 }
};

// character enumeration
String.forEach = function(string, block, context) {
 Array.forEach(string.split(""), function(chr, index) {
  block.call(context, chr, index, string);
 });
};

// globally resolve forEach enumeration
var forEach = function(object, block, context) {
 if (object) {
  var resolve = Object; // default
  if (object instanceof Function) {
   // functions have a "length" property
   resolve = Function;
  } else if (object.forEach instanceof Function) {
   // the object implements a custom forEach method so use that
   object.forEach(block, context);
   return;
  } else if (typeof object == "string") {
   // the object is a string
   resolve = String;
  } else if (typeof object.length == "number") {
   // the object is array-like
   resolve = Array;
  }
  resolve.forEach(object, block, context);
 }
};
```

and the secont script is condition.js

```js
function contition() {
var list = new Array();

list[0] = "calmbfr^<img src='wr-el-calm.png' width='40'>";
list[1] = "---bfr^<img src='wr-el-calm.png' width='40'>";

var j, k, find, item, page, repl;
for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
item = list[i].split("^");
find = item[0];
repl = item[1];
page = document.body.innerHTML;
while (page.indexOf(find) >= 0) {
var j = page.indexOf(find);
var k = find.length;
page = page.substr(0,j) + repl + page.substr(j+k);
document.body.innerHTML = page;
}
}
}
```

the second script run only with body onload="contition()"

if i run seerate the scripts its ok but when i run together in html and give body onload="contition()" work only the secont script and not the sortable.js

below is the html code

```html
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die("Error connecting to database: ".mysql_error());
    /*
        localhost - it's location of the mysql server, usually localhost
        root - your username
        third is your password
         
        if connection fails it will stop loading the page and display an error
    */
     
    mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());
    /* database is the name of database we've created */
?>
 


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="el-gr" lang="el-gr" >

<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    

    <link href="contnow.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="meteogram_table.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



 <script src="sorttable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.3.js'></script>

<script>
//<![CDATA[ 
function contition() {
var list = new Array();

list[0] = "calmbfr^<img src='/ajaxImages/wr-el-calm.png' width='40'>";
list[1] = "---bfr^<img src='/ajaxImages/wr-el-calm.png' width='40'>";

var j, k, find, item, page, repl;
for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
item = list[i].split("^");
find = item[0];
repl = item[1];
page = document.body.innerHTML;
while (page.indexOf(find) >= 0) {
var j = page.indexOf(find);
var k = find.length;
page = page.substr(0,j) + repl + page.substr(j+k);
document.body.innerHTML = page;
}
}
}
//]]>
 </script>

 </head>



 <body onload="contition()"
 bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
  
  
  
  <div id="menu">
   <ul>
    <li id="button1"><a href="view_wu_metars_GR.php" title="">
    Ελλάδα</a></li>
    <li id="button2"><a href="view_wu_metars_NGR.php" title="">
    Βόρεια Ελ.</a></li>
    <li id="button3"><a href="view_wu_metars_WGR.php" title="">
    Δυτικη Ελ.</a></li>
    <li id="button4"><a href="view_wu_metars_CGR.php" title="">
    Κεντρική Ελ.</a></li>
    <li id="button5"><a href="view_wu_metars_SGR.php" title="">
    Νότια Ελ.</a></li>
    <li id="button6"><a href="view_wu_metars_Islands.php" title="">
    Νησιά</a></li>
    <li id="button7"><a href="view_wu_metars_Airports.php" title="">
    Αεροδρόμια</a></li>
    <li id="button8"><a href="view_wu_metars_Balkans.php" title="">
    Βαλκάνια</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  




  
<table class='sortable' width="1000px" height="" border="1" bgcolor="#ecf9ff" bordercolor="#008080" style="font-size: 13px;">
   <thead bgcolor="#66CCFF">
 <tr>
   <th>Καιρικές <br> συνθήκες</th>
  <th>Περιοχή</th>
  <th>Πόλη/ <br> περιοχή</th>
  <th style width="110px">Ενημέρωση</th>
  <th>Θερμοκρασία <br> (°C)</th>
  <th>Υγρασία <br> (%)</th>
  <th>Σημείο  <br> Δρόσου <br> (°C)</th>
  <th>Πίεση <br> (hpa)</th>
  <th>Υετός <br> ώρας</th>
     <th>Υετός <br> (mm)</th>
  <th>Διεύθυνση <br> Ανέμου</th>
  <th>Άνεμος <br> (Bfr)</th>
  <th>Τύπος <br> Σταθμού</th>
        <th><a>Υψό-<br>μετρο<br>m</a></th>
     </tr>
       </thead>

<tr align='center'>  
 
      <?php
$result = mysql_query('SELECT    *
FROM        wuMETAR_icon_LGTS
ORDER BY  id DESC
LIMIT     1;') or die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());



//print values to screen
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo "

     
  <td>---bfr</td>
";
              
            }

// Free the resources associated with the result set
// This is done automatically at the end of the script
mysql_free_result($result);

?>  
<?php
$result = mysql_query('SELECT    *
FROM      wu_AgionOros_MoniMegistisLavras
ORDER BY  id DESC
LIMIT     1;') or die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());



//print values to screen
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo "

    
  <td><b>Άγιον όρος</b></td>
  <td><b>Μονή Μεγίστης Λάυρας</b></td>
        <td><b style='font-size: 10px;'>".$row['observation_time']."</b></td>
  <td style='font-size: 22px; font-weight: bold;'>".$row['temp_c']."</td>
        <td style='font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;'>".$row['relative_humidity']."</td>
        <td><b>".$row['dewpoint_c']."</b></td>
  <td>".$row['pressure_mb']."</td>
        <th>".$row['precip_1hr_metric']."</th>
        <td><img width='35px' height='50px' src='/DFS/data/wu/CURRENTXML/mm/".$row['precip_today_metric'].".gif'/></td>
  <td><img width='50px' height='50px' src='".$row['wind_dir'].".gif'/></td>
  <td><img width='55px' height='55px' src='".$row['wind_mph'].".gif'/></td>
  <td><img width='50px' height='50px' src='".$row['station_type'].".gif'/></td>
     <td><b>142</b></td>
";

            }

// Free the resources associated with the result set
// This is done automatically at the end of the script
mysql_free_result($result);

?> 
 </tr>
</body>
</html>
```

html is bigest but 30000 characters can upload here
my question is how can run this scripts together in html page?
i found the problem is sortable.js run without body onload but the second script need body onload.
can anyone tell me how change the script code for condition.js to work without body onload?
ps: the script condition.js i need to run in the same table with sortable table and i change only the first td of every tr 
please help me because the other solution is to create 600000 weather icons but with condition.js is better
thanks

Comment: Please narrow this down to the absolute minimum code for your question.

Comment: @Alex
if limiting the code can not properly explain my question.
take out the code from sortable.js

Comment: Have you tried including your script tags at the bottom of your page, that will mean the JS is included once the DOM has loaded, you're probably getting issues because your page hasn't loaded yet, so sortable cant find the root nodes it needs to reference.

Comment: yes i try this solution but no difference .
here is the link of the page http://dfsbeta.dramaweather.gr/DFS/data/wu/CURRENTXML/view_wu_metars_NGR_icon.php , you may notice that the sortable.js WORKS just refresh the page for a few seconds if missed and click on the table

Comment: you still have 2 scripts in your header - move them to the bottom, and in the correct order

Comment: and here the link for same html when i stop body onload http://dfsbeta.dramaweather.gr/DFS/data/wu/CURRENTXML/view_wu_metars_NGR_without_onload.php here work fine sortable

Comment: and your scripts are still in the head...

Comment: move scripts at bottom but the same result

Answer (score 0):

i found a similar solution to work together sortable.js with script to change text to image

```js
 
$(document).ready(function () {
$("td:contains('40.0clear 0')").html('<img src="/CURRENTXML/Clear.gif" height="40px" width="50px"/>');
});

$(document).ready(function () {
$("td:contains('40.0clear 1.png')").html('<img src="/CURRENTXML/rain.gif" alt="40.0clear 1.png" height="40px" width="50px"/>');
});
   
$(document).ready(function () {
$("td:contains('2.0clear 1.png')").html('<img src="/CURRENTXML/snow.gif" alt="40.0clear 1.png" height="40px" width="50px"/>');
});
```